# What is the purpose of conducting Simple Random Sampling WITH Replacement?

Tags: machine-learning, sampling, data-mining

Part of data preparation is simple random sampling. Random sampling can be of two forms with replacement or without replacement. **With replacement, subset sampling simply might contain *duplicates* of original dataset objects**. Why would be useful to have duplicates while also as a part of data cleaning process is to eliminate duplicates?

Comment: “part of data cleaning process is to eliminate duplicates”—this is not always desirable. Anyway, sampling data points with replacement makes its best-known appearance in [bootstrapping](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)).

Comment: Sampling with replacement gives independent samples, as for the independent Bernoulli trials that make up a binomial distribution.. Sampling without replacement yields dependent observations, often modeled by a hypergeometric distribution. // When taking a small sample from a relatively large population there may be little practical difference between sampling with and without replacement. // Also, as mentioned by @AryaMcCarthy, bootstrapping involves 're-sampling' with replacement from a sample, often to get a confidence interval for a population parameter based on the sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Example 1, without replacement:**  An urn contains 5 red marbles and 3 green ones. Two marbles are taken at random without replacement. What is the probability both are red?

$$P(R_1R_2) = P(R_1)P(R_2|R_1) = (5/8)(4/7) \\= 20/56 = 0.3571,$$
to four places.

In R, where `dhyper` is a hypergeometric PDF, we have:

```
dhyper(2, 5,3, 2)
[1] 0.3571429
```

If we sample 3 marbles without replacement, what is the
probability that exactly 2 of them will be red? Answer: $\frac{{5\choose 2}{3\choose 1}}{8\choose 3} = 0.5357.$

```
dhyper(2, 5,3, 3)
[1] 0.5357143
choose(5,2)*choose(3,1)/choose(8,3)
[1] 0.5357143
```

**Example 2, with replacement:** Same urn. Sample with replacement, same questions. In R, `dbinom` is a binomial PDF.

Probability of two red in two draws: $(5/8)^2 = 0.3906.$
Probability of exactly two red in three draws: $3(5/8)^2(3/8) = 0.4395.$ (Compare with  0.5357 without replacement.)

```
dbinom(2, 2, 5/8)
[1] 0.390625
dbinom(2, 3, 5/8)
[1] 0.4394531
```

**Example 3: Large population.** Less difference between sampling with and without replacement. Suppose the urn has 800 red and 300 green marbles.

Probability of getting exactly 2 reds in 3 draws without replacement (hypergeometric). Answer: $0.4402.$ [Can you do the computation without R?]

```
dhyper(2, 500,300, 3)
[1] 0.4402237
```

Probability of getting exactly 2 reds in 3 draws with replacement (binomial). Answer: $0.4395.$ (This is exactly the same as for the small urn. Also, compare with the
answer just above for sampling without replacement it is now about the same as for sampling with replacement: Both values round to $0.44.$

```
dbinom(2, 3, 5/8)
[1] 0.4394531
```

This illustrates that the difference between with and without replacement has minimal impact for large populations.

---

I'm not sure how much detail you want or whether this is getting ahead of your course. If you want to
see computation of a bootstrap confidence interval,
leave a comment and I will try to show you a simple one.

---

***Addendum* on bootstrap re-sampling with replacement.**

Consider a dataset `x` of size $n = 20$ from a normal population.

```
set.seed(620)
x = rnorm(20, 50, 7)
summary(x);  length(x);  sd(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  41.14   43.46   47.92   49.39   54.29   62.36 
[1] 20        ## sample size
[1] 6.762375  ## sample standard deviation
```

If you know the sample is from some normal distribution, then you can
use a t 95% confidence interval for $\mu$ $(46.22, 52.55)$, which R computes along with its `t.test` procedure:

```
t.test(x)$conf.int
[1] 46.22472 52.55450
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

[Because this is fictitious data simulated in R, I happen to know that the CI includes the population mean $\mu=50,$ but in a practical application,
you never know the true value of $\mu$ for sure.]

If you had no idea from what population the data `x` were sampled,
then you couldn't be sure a t confidence interval is valid. What I
can say for sure is that the population contains the 20 observations
I have and that the sample mean is $\bar X = 49.39.$

A simple 95% nonparametric bootstrap CI can be found using the quantile method as follows. [This isn't the 'best' bootstrap method, but it is
simple and will do for an illustration here.]

I use the R procedure `sample` with parameter `rep=T` to take a
sample of size $n = 20$ with replacement from 'x', and find
its sample mean $\bar X_1^*.$ Then I do the same thing $B = 2000$ times
getting re-samples mean $\bar X_i^*, i = 1,2,\dots, B.$ In the computer
code below these are in the 2000-vecter `a.re`.

That gives me an idea what the distribution of $\bar X$ might be. Then I use quantiles $0.025$ and $0.975$ of `a.re` as the endpoints of my
95% bootstrap CI $(46.77, 52.52).$ Another run of the bootstrap program
would give a slightly different CI because bootstrapping is a random
process. [Another run without the `set.seed` statement, gave CI
$(46.49, 52.37)$. It probably makes sense to round endpoints to one place.]

Bearing in mind that the bootstrap
procedure makes no assumptions about the population (except that it has
a mean), it is remarkable how close the CI is to the t CI obtained before.

```
set.seed(2021);  B = 2000
a.re = replicate(B, mean(sample(x, rep=T)))
quantile(a.re, c(.025,.975))
    2.5%    97.5% 
46.77409 52.52437 

hdr = "Bootstrap Dist'n of Re-sampled Means"
hist(a.re, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
 abline(v=c(46.77, 52.52), col="orange", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

*Notes:*

(1) In bootstrapping, you're manipulating a data set of size $n$ by taking re-samples of size $n.$ If you did that re-sampling without replacement,- you'd just the same dataset back (in a different order); by re-sampling *with replacement* you can get many different results, thus exploring the variability of possible alternative datasets. In my program above, all $B=2000$ values in `a.re` were different.

```
length(unique(a.re))
[1] 2000
```

(2) It is important to understand that bootstrap 're-sampling' does not
produce additional information. It is an analytical procedure. (Also, making a t confidence interval would produce no new information; just
presents current information in a potentially more useful way.)

(3) If the bootstrap distribution in the histogram above were not roughly
symmetrical, I would have to do a more sophisticated bootstrap procedure.

Comment: thank you @BruceET for your details provided. To wrap up what you said is that conducting random sampling with or without replacement won't have impact on result with large amount of data? and another benefit is that replacement is used for data bootstrapping?

Comment: I'd say the difference between with and without replacement has minimal impact for _large populations._ // In bootstrapping, you're manipulating a _data set_ of size $n$ by taking re-samples of size $n.$ If you did that re-sampling _without replacement,- you'd just the same dataset back; by re-sampling _with replacement_ you can get many different results, thus exploring the variability of possible alternative datasets.

Comment: thank you @BruceET, can you please include the last comment to your answer to accept it. Thanks again for your effort

Comment: Hope you can make some sense of the bootstrap I added at the end.

Comment: Thank you @BruceET, I am going to approve but please add this "I'd say the difference between with and without replacement has minimal impact for large populations. // In bootstrapping, you're manipulating a data set of size n by taking re-samples of size n. If you did that re-sampling without replacement,- you'd just the same dataset back; by re-sampling _with replacement you can get many different results, thus exploring the variability of possible alternative datasets" because my question is to understand the overall view of both, not just how to apply. thanks :)

Comment: Both of these points now appear explicitly in my Answer. One just before bootstrapping the other in Note (1).